# Measurable Function Proof Help

Tags: measure-theory

How to I prove that f is measurable if f is a real function of a measurable space $X$ such that $\{x ; f(x) \geq r\}$ is measurable for every rational $r$.

From my basic understanding I need to prove that $f^{-1}(U)$ is measurable where U is the union of countably open balls with rational radii?

Comment: It suffices to prove that $\{x : f(x) \geq c\}$ is measurable for every real $c$ (why?), so try expressing $\{x : f(x) \geq c\}$ in terms of sets of the form $\{x : f(x) \geq r\}$, where $r$ is rational.

Comment: Thanks I think I get it. {x:f(x)≥c} is measurable for every real c because it is the union of countably infinite sets of {x:f(x)≥r} and countable unions of measurable sets are measurable.

Comment: @Nebulae Intersection, not union.

Comment: Intersection? I don't understand.